# Как и где хранить посты и другую информацию

Tags: веб-программирование, backend

всем привет. очень нужна помощь опытных разработчиков веба.
расскажите пожалуйста, как и где хранить публикуемые пользователями посты на сайте который я разрабатываю? при этом нужно учитывать что помимо хранения постов, мне нужно будет их отдавать пользователям, показывать отметки этих постов(просмотры/лайки/репосты), как то сохранять эти отметки.

Comment: Любое хранилище. Файл, БД, да хоть в памяти

Comment: базы данных или json, но лучше базы данных

Comment: @Olegator36 очень спорное утверждение, особенно в части JSON, преобразование из JSON в бинарные данные - тяжелая операция :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я в принципе смогу хранить посты в бд. но вопросы есть: какая бд(обычный постгрес или редис). и если хранить в бд, то как отдавать пользователю посты по определённым тегам, которых на одном. посте может быть 20шт.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я в принципе смогу хранить посты в бд. но вопросы есть: какая бд(обычный постгрес или редис). и если хранить в бд, то как отдавать пользователю посты по определённым тегам, которых на одном. посте может быть 20шт.

Comment: постгрес, mysql, mongo, mssql, да что угодно. то что нравится, то и берите...... как хранить это уже выходит за рамки вопроса....это вообще относится к проектированию БД. так что не вижу смысл это тут обсуждать....всё же ресурс не дискусионный.

Comment: редис в первую очередь кеш и не гарантирует сохранности данных без специальных танцев с бубном. может использоваться дополнительно с долговременной БД для увеличения производительности. postgres вполне подходит. А как именно хранить зависит от точно поставленной задачи. Просто посты, обычно достаточно одной таблицы, лайки явно вторая таблица, просмотры скорее всего третья, но могут быть нюансы связанные с производительностью. Теги - четвертая, принадлежность постов тегам пятая, ну и так далее. Может таких 5 таблиц хватит, а может еще штук 20 придется делать, если тонкости задачи того потребуют